# How do you extract lines with two conditions from txt file, a word and a number?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get the numbers in valid lines only with Python so 
1234, 345.2, 3455 from line 1
7644, 6564.1, 1325 from line 3
89473, 8479, 2434 from line 5

```
txt file

books|1234|345.2|3455|valid
books|9875|5466.1|invalid
books|7644|6564.1|1325|valid
books|5435|4535.2|invalid
books|89473|8479|2434|valid
```

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?

Comment: 1234, 345.2, 3455 from line one, 
7644, 6564.1, 1325 from line three,
89473, 8479, 2434 from line five

Comment: you can split the lines on `|` and check if the last element is "valid" then gather your numbers from your valid lines no ?

Comment: Hey @Galyfray  You got a code for this?

Comment: someone already wrote some code corresponding to what I said in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("test.txt",'r') as fil: #open file
    for line in fil.readlines(): #read it line by line
        #remove newline and split into list, elements separated by |
        temp=line.strip().split('|') 
        if temp[-1]=="valid": #Check if "valid" is last element
            print(temp[1:-1]) #print all elements between first and last
```

This is just printing the values, but it should be fairly easy to instead store the values however you want.